# Contradiction about Archimedes' principle. Where did I make my mistake?

Tags: calculus, analysis

This $\textbf{Fact}$ is true.

$\textbf{Fact}$

$0\leqq a < \epsilon $ for all $\epsilon >0$
$\Longrightarrow$ $a=0.$

$\textbf{Proof of Fact}$

Suppose $a\neq 0.$

Then, $a>0$.

Because $\epsilon $ is arbitrary, I can set $\epsilon = \dfrac{a}{2}$.

Now, $a<\epsilon= \dfrac{a}{2}$ so $1<\dfrac{1}{2}$. It's a contradiction.

So the $\textbf{Fact}$ is true.

But if I use this $\textbf{Fact}$, the contradiction happens.

Let $\epsilon >0 $ positive.

From Archimedes' principle, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\epsilon > 1$.

Then, $\dfrac{1}{n}<\epsilon$.

And because $\dfrac{1}{n}$ is positive, $0\leqq \dfrac{1}{n}<\epsilon.$

If I use the $\textbf{Fact}$, $\dfrac{1}{n}=0.$

But $\dfrac{1}{n}=0$ cannot be true.

Where did I make my mistake?

Comment: "There exists $n\in \Bbb N$ means, $n$ is fixed. So the assumption $1/n<\epsilon$ is not satisfied for *all* $\epsilon$. So we cannot conclude $a=1/n=0$.

Comment: You misinterpreted/disregarded the quantifier '*for all*' before the $\epsilon$.